# How to divide a record and show specific part of it

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have table with 4 columns.

```
user_id,  user_name,  password,  full_name
706    ,  29682    ,  29682   ,  Nikolay Valeriev Rusanov
707    ,  30211    ,  30211   ,  Valentin Ognyanov Karamanchev
```

When i make the selection i need to show only the last name from the column **full_name**.

Query should return

```
user_id,  user_name,  password,  full_name
706    ,  29682    ,  29682   ,  Rusanov
707    ,  30211    ,  30211   ,  Karamanchev
```

They are separated with "space".
I can't use substr, because every record in the column have different length and i have more than 10 000 rows.

Can u guys give me some sql query how to do it??

Comment: @Filburt show me were is the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.**
Using simple `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` :

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 'Nikolay Valeriev Rusanov' full_name FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'Valentin Ognyanov Karamanchev' FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 'no reason' FROM dual)
  5  SELECT SUBSTR(full_name,instr(full_name,' ',-1)+1) last_name
  6  FROM DATA
  7  /

LAST_NAME
-----------------------------
Rusanov
Karamanchev
reason

SQL>
```

**2.**
Using `REGULAR EXPRESSION` :

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 'Nikolay Valeriev Rusanov' full_name FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'Valentin Ognyanov Karamanchev' FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 'no reason' FROM dual)
  5  SELECT regexp_substr (full_name, '\w*$') last_name
  6  FROM DATA
  7  /

LAST_NAME
-----------------------------
Rusanov
Karamanchev
reason

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks alot, perfect answer! Appreciate a lot!

Comment: You can mark it answered.